# Using Different Webcams in Angular Component Based on Device Type

Tags: angular, webcam

I'm working on an Angular component where I need to utilize the webcam functionality. I'm aiming to achieve the following behaviors:

When the app is opened on a PC, I want to use the first detected webcam.
When the app is accessed from a mobile device, I want to set the rear-facing camera as the default.
Here's the HTML template code:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>is DESK: {{ isDesktop }}</h1>
  <div>
    <webcam
      [height]="500"
      [width]="500"
      [trigger]="triggerObservable"
      (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)"
      *ngIf="showWebcam"
      [allowCameraSwitch]="false"
      [switchCamera]="nextWebcamObservable"
      [videoOptions]="videoOptions"
      (cameraSwitched)="cameraWasSwitched($event)"
      (initError)="handleInitError($event)"
    ></webcam>
    <br />
    <div class="actionBtn" (click)="triggerSnapshot()" title="Take Picture">
      
    </div>
    <div class="actionBtn" (click)="showNextWebcam(true)" title="Switch Camera">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h4 *ngIf="errors.length > 0">Messages:</h4>
<ul *ngFor="let error of errors">
  <li>{{ error | json }}</li>
</ul>

import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { WebcamImage, WebcamInitError } from 'ngx-webcam';
import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';
import { WebcamUtil } from 'ngx-webcam';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-camera',
  templateUrl: './camera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./camera.component.scss'],
})
export class CameraComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output()
  public pictureTaken = new EventEmitter<WebcamImage>();
  isDesktop: boolean;

  // toggle webcam on/off
  public showWebcam = true;
  public allowCameraSwitch = true;
  public multipleWebcamsAvailable = false;
  public deviceId: string;
  mode: string = 'user'; //Set front camera for pc
  public videoOptions: MediaTrackConstraints = {
    width: { min: 640 },
    height: { min: 480 },
    facingMode: { ideal: this.mode },
  };
  public webcamOptions: WebcamUtil = {
    video: {
      facingMode: 'environment', // Questa opzione dovrebbe impostare la videocamera posteriore
    },
  };
  public errors: WebcamInitError[] = [];

  // webcam snapshot trigger
  private trigger: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  // switch to next / previous / specific webcam; true/false: forward/backwards, string: deviceId
  private nextWebcam: Subject<boolean | string> = new Subject<
    boolean | string
  >();

  constructor(private deviceDetector: DeviceDetectorService) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    WebcamUtil.getAvailableVideoInputs().then(
      (mediaDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) => {
        this.multipleWebcamsAvailable = mediaDevices && mediaDevices.length > 1;
      }
    );
    this.isDesktop = this.deviceDetector.isDesktop();
    this.isDesktop = this.deviceDetector.isDesktop();
    if (!this.isDesktop) {
      this.mode = 'environment'; // Set rear camera for mobile
      this.getBackCameraForced();
    }
  }

  getBackCameraForced(): void {
    WebcamUtil.getAvailableVideoInputs().then(
      (mediaDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) => {
        console.log(mediaDevices);

        const backCamera = mediaDevices.find((device) => {
          return device.label.includes('back');
        });
        if (backCamera) {
          this.videoOptions = {
            ...this.videoOptions,
            facingMode: { ideal: 'environment' },
            deviceId: { exact: backCamera.deviceId },
          };
        }
      }
    );
  }

  public triggerSnapshot(): void {
    this.trigger.next();
  }

  public toggleWebcam(): void {
    this.showWebcam = !this.showWebcam;
  }

  public handleInitError(error: WebcamInitError): void {
    this.errors.push(error);
  }

  public showNextWebcam(directionOrDeviceId: boolean | string): void {
    // true => move forward through devices
    // false => move backwards through devices
    // string => move to device with given deviceId
    this.nextWebcam.next(directionOrDeviceId);
  }

  public handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
    console.info('received webcam image', webcamImage);
    this.pictureTaken.emit(webcamImage);
  }

  public cameraWasSwitched(deviceId: string): void {
    console.log('active device: ' + deviceId);
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
  }

  public get triggerObservable(): Observable<void> {
    return this.trigger.asObservable();
  }

  public get nextWebcamObservable(): Observable<boolean | string> {
    return this.nextWebcam.asObservable();
  }
}
```

thi is a stakcblit link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-webcam-demo-gsmzsv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcamera%2Fcamera.component.ts
'''

Comment: When I visit the StackBlitz on my iPhone [the console only shows an array with a single camera/device on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sznlr.png). my iPhone does have 2 cameras though, so I suspect something is not working correctly with `WebcamUtil`